# SQL Server Query - Combining Select Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a feeling that I am being really stupid here. But despite 3 hours of online reserach I cannot see what I am missing.

I have a MS-SQL table of invoices which I am trying to group by year AND customer reference. This is the query which I have put together:

```
SELECT year(INVOICE_DATE)AS YEAR, month (invoice_date)AS MONTH, sum(invoice_net) As invoice_net
FROM            S50INVOICE
--WHERE       ACCOUNT_REF = 'ONLINE' OR Account_ref = 'BADSALES' OR ACCOUNT_REF = 'WEBSALES'
WHERE       ACCOUNT_REF = 'cash'
--WHERE       ACCOUNT_REF <> 'ONLINE' OR Account_ref <> 'BADSALES' OR ACCOUNT_REF <> 'WEBSALES' or ACCOUNT_REF <> 'CASH'
GROUP BY year(invoice_date), month(invoice_date)
order by YEAR, MONTH
```

Now I can run this 3 times using one of the WHERE statements each time and I get three tables of Year/Month/Invoice Net.

But I want to be able to run this one time and get one table with Year/Invoice/Account_Ref(Condition 1)/Account_Ref(Condition 2)/Account_Ref (Condition 3).

My thinking is that I should be using UNION but trying this seems to break the Group statement and I still only get 3 columns returned.

Comment: sounds like you should be able to modify your logic so that your 3 WHERE statements are separated by OR.  Then you need to think about your groupings, are the accounts unique the the groupings?   If yes, just use MIN(..) or MAX on the column to make it an aggregate

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a bit tricky but should work more or less with my proposal.
The groups are not changing, it is all about the way you calculate the totals for groups based in the WHERE condition but in a CASE Clause.
I cannot test it because there is no DDL for your question but... please, let me know if that is Ok:

```
SELECT 
    year(INVOICE_DATE)AS YEAR, 
    month (invoice_date)AS MONTH, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN ACCOUNT_REF = 'ONLINE' 
           OR Account_ref = 'BADSALES' 
           OR ACCOUNT_REF = 'WEBSALES' 
        THEN invoice_net ELSE 0 END) As invoice_net_Cond1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ACCOUNT_REF = 'cash' 
        THEN invoice_net ELSE 0 END) As invoice_net_Cond2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN ACCOUNT_REF <> 'ONLINE' 
           OR Account_ref <> 'BADSALES' 
           OR ACCOUNT_REF <> 'WEBSALES' 
           or ACCOUNT_REF <> 'CASH'  
        THEN invoice_net ELSE 0 END) As invoice_net_Cond3
FROM S50INVOICE 
GROUP BY year(invoice_date), month(invoice_date) 
ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT year(INVOICE_DATE) AS YEAR, month (invoice_date) AS MONTH, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN ACCOUNT_REF IN ('ONLINE', 'BADSALES' 'WEBSALES' )
                THEN invoice_net ELSE 0
           END) As invoice_net_Cond1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ACCOUNT_REF = 'cash' THEN invoice_net ELSE 0
           END) As invoice_net_Cond2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN ACCOUNT_REF NOT IN ('ONLINE', 'BADSALES', 'WEBSALES', 'CASH') 
                THEN invoice_net ELSE 0
           END) As invoice_net_Cond3
FROM S50INVOICE 
GROUP BY year(invoice_date), month(invoice_date) 
ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH;
```